# Absolute url path with php is redirecting to 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I would like to know how not to redirect 404 error page when I am trying to give an absolute path with php extension. But in other extensions, it's all opening good.

There might be a good chance that in .htaccess files, somehow php linked with 404 error.

But I don't how to do it.

> As an example:

```
http://www.demotest.com/test/test.php (this link redirect me to 404 error page)

http://www.demotest.com/test/test.js (open fine, no redirect to 404 error)
http://www.demotest.com/test/test.css (open fine, no redirect to 404 error)
http://www.demotest.com/test/image1.jpg  (all media files are also open fine, no redirect to 404 error)
```

But that php is redirecting to 404 error. How to stop it to redirect. I want it to show the blank page if nothing is there in PHP code. But right now it's not happening. So need your help on this.

Comment: Stupid question but you never know... you do have a test.php file in your test directory ? Could you provide us with your .htaccess and/or virtualhost config ?

Comment: @Growiel Not a stupid question at all. I was about to ask the same and it is a good question, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to joomla .htaccess file, try to rename .htaccess and it wont show you 404.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Finally I solved the issue.

What I  have done is just made an exception in that particular php file in htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^test\/test\.php$ - [L]
```

And that's it. The link is now open nicely without redirect to 404 error page.